# Why is this UILabel with NSAttributedString not showing?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am attempting to create a key for a chart, and I need to have a string followed by a colored box, then another string following this. However, the text is not showing up when attempting this. I haven't worked with attributed strings before, so it may be something obvious. Thanks!

```
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 30, 30)];
myBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test string"];
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [self imageWithView:myBox];

CGFloat oldWidth = textAttachment.image.size.width;

CGFloat scaleFactor = oldWidth / (titleLabel.frame.size.width - 10);
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment.image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(6, 1) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: As a sanity check, does the label appear if you set it with plain text?

Comment: It was working previous to setting the attributed text, when I had it set with plain text.

Comment: You are calling `imageWithView` on your own view while that view is being constructed. I'm not sure what exactly you expect to happen. Or is `imageWithView` just returning a rectangular image?

Comment: I am just trying to create a rectangular image with it.